My Ubuntu 24.04 desktop has an "Unknown Display"
I recently decided to try out Ubuntu 24.04 as a desktop system. I'm using a GeForce RTX 2060 and "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary).
For some reason I have an "Unknown Display".  How can I identify where it comes from and how to get rid of it?
It's annoying because my mouse can disappear into it.



Your display seems to be a TV. Are you using a laptop and a TV as a monitor?

No, it's a 38" LG Widescreen connected via DisplayPort. https://www.lg.com/au/monitors/ultrawide/38wn95c-w/
